# Rewriting glyphicon code for Font Awesome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fontawesome-4.4.0

I'm currently using the following code to display a couple glyphicons (glyphicon-chevron-down and glyphicon-remove-sign) with my headers:

```
<h2 class="h2Article collapsed" id="a4" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#b4" aria-expanded="false"><span class="Article"><span class="label label-primary"><small><span class="only-collapsed glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span><span class="only-expanded glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></small> Acquired LifeTags</span></span></h2>
```

I just discovered Font Awesome's latest library and want to try it out. How should I modify the code above to replace glyphicon-chevron-down with this?

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-2x"></i>
```

P.S. I should add that I'd like to simplify my code, if possible. Four separate spans is too much. ;)

Comment: P.S. Is it correct to call Font Awesome's characters glyphicons, or are glyphicons and Font Awesome two different things?

Comment: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ vs http://glyphicons.com/ ; two different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
<span class="only-collapsed glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
```

by

```
<i class="only-collapsed fa fa-chevron-down fa-2x"></i>
```

no more :P

You should end up with something like this :

```
<h2 class="h2Article collapsed Article label label-primary" id="a4"
     data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#b4" aria-expanded="false">
    <small>
        <i class="only-collapsed fa fa-chevron-down fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="only-expanded glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i>
    </small>
    &nbsp;Acquired LifeTags
</h2>
```